# Looping through variable values inside a 2-dimensional DataArray

Tags: python, loops, python-xarray

I have a DataArray for which I access the variable 'PM2_5_DRY' at the lowest level:

```
var = ds.PM2_5_DRY.sel(bottom_up=0)
```

This gives me a 2 dimensional DataArray object:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'PM2_5_DRY' (south_north: 115, west_east: 115)>
array([[ 8.908906,  9.488876, 10.119942, ..., 27.426315, 28.08993 , 28.891764],
       [ 8.816208,  9.239424,  9.847547, ..., 24.507416, 25.262184, 29.127642],
       [ 8.721322,  9.133161,  9.733953, ..., 24.207502, 25.352211, 28.9906  ],
       ...,
       [11.714283, 11.558845, 11.947604, ..., 16.11631 , 15.923126, 15.798327],
       [11.547533, 11.392885, 11.900793, ..., 16.067215, 15.874124, 15.757443],
       [11.373323, 11.92701 , 12.316559, ..., 16.067123, 15.881643, 15.734135]],
      dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
    XLAT     (south_north, west_east) float32 ...
    XLONG    (south_north, west_east) float32 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: south_north, west_east
```

Now, I want to loop through each value inside.

for each value, if it is greater than N, I need to set it == 2; else ==1:

```
for i in var[i,:]:
    for j in var [:,j]:
        if var[i,j] > denr:
            # Set var[i,j] to 1
            var[i,j] == 2
        else:
            var[i,j] == 1
```

However, I receive this error code

```
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

I am not sure if xarray.DataArray is an iterable. I think not; hence the error code.

What other ways are there so that I could do

1. Loop through the values of the xarray
2. Replace the value if it is greater than N
3. Save it as a new DataArray

Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something similar with

> numpy.where () ==> xarray.where()

Syntax is xr.where(var>condition, X, Y)

where, X is the value to replace if condition is true, and Y is the value if false.

```
a = np.where(var> 40, 2, 1)
```

This returned a masked DataArray object.

```
<xarray.DataArray 'PM2_5_DRY' (south_north: 115, west_east: 115)>
array([[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       ...,
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]])
Coordinates:
    XLAT     (south_north, west_east) float32 14.086861 14.086884 ... 15.111992
    XLONG    (south_north, west_east) float32 120.4978 120.50708 ... 121.55762
Dimensions without coordinates: south_north, west_east
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use pandas `DataFrame` instead, with a combination of `lambda` and a `for in` loop, like so (hopefully the below code is self-explanatory).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
                [
                [10, 15, 20],
                [25, 30, 35],
                [40, 45, 50],
                [55, 60, 65]
                ])

a=2
b=1
n=40

condition = lambda x: a if x > n else b

for column in df:
    df[column]=df[column].apply(condition)

print(df)
```

The output should be:

```
   0  1  2
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  1
2  1  2  2
3  2  2  2
```